# How do I read a list of numbers in Python, if they are on different lines?

Tags: python, input

I only recently began learning Python and found a set of problems that I am now working through. One  requires reading a set of numbers, inputted like this:

```
0 16
1 8
5 5
10 2
```

,etc.

The length of the input (the number of lines) is unspecified, so I can't use `in range`. I tried using `input().split()` with the `'\n'` character, but for some reason (could someone explain?) it doesn't work. How do I read this list?

Comment: from where are you trying to read this list? Is it a file or what?

Comment: "tried using input().split() with the '\n' character" `input` reads just a single line, so that can not work.

Comment: `input()` reads lines: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Comment: You need numbers as list?

Comment: @Flavio Moraes No, I am practicing for a competition, and the input is entered into a compiler, I don't quite know how to explain. This is what it looks like: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_fxI4ACBNtnQ_Bvp9UIYZgHy2IItJcV9/view?usp=sharing   I apologize for the Russian, the big window is titled 'Enter your code here', the small box at the left is 'Input', and the one on the right is 'Output'

Comment: what do you get when you print your input?

Comment: @tobias_k  oh, yes, that seem obvious now. thanks.Would it be possible to do something like this:
```lst=[[int(i) for i in input().split() ]for k in input().split('\n)]```

Comment: @FlavioMoraes I don't quite understand, what do you mean?

Comment: if you do `print(input()) ´ what does it prints out?

Comment: @FlavioMoraes It would print just the first line of input, so '0 16 ' in this case.

Comment: Ok, it means that your input is only one line and not a list as you thought. So it makes no sense to split it. What happens if you print the input two times?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224303/discussion-between-flavio-moraes-and-ira-i-i).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sys.stdin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) to read all the available input. Just treat it as you would any ordinary file.

```
import sys

nums = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in sys.stdin]
print(nums)
```

With your input in the `inp` file:

```
>>> python3 test.py < inp
[[0, 16], [1, 8], [5, 5], [10, 2]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly! I only want to ask, why did you write ```list``` before the rest of the code? Don't square brackets already specify that?

Comment: @IraI.I. The square brackets make the outer list, but for the inner lists, the `map` generator has to be collected in a `list`, too, for each element.